# Ubuntu: Alternative task-switcher to what is provided in compiz

Tags: ubuntu, compiz

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 and really enjoying it.

The task switcher default in Ubuntu shows a list of small icons for each running app much like the windows task switcher.  It's fast and effective.

I enabled Compiz and noticed that the task switcher changed to one with small thumbnails showing a smaller version of each window.  Nice, but it slows the task manager down to about 0.5 seconds to display, which for me is far too long.

Have googled the forums and it's a very common problem with ubuntu/compiz.  I want to run compiz as it provides so many other features, but the slow task switcher is just not going to run with me.

So was wondering if there is some way of NOT letting compiz override the task switcher, or, if there is some other task switcher that I can install which will not be slow like the compiz one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And second pro-tip: move on to 12.04 at least, 11.04 does not get updates (and especially security updates) any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to system --> preferences --> CompizConfig....
In there search for Application Switcher, should be under window management, and disable the one that is used. This should get rid of it although I can't test it because my computer is so lame it doesn't even run compiz D:

Pro tip https://askubuntu.com/ is for Ubuntu questions, should be easier to get a good answer there ;) you can use the same login as here.